# Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' on react native cli run android

Tags: android, react-native

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file 'C:\Users\PC\stuff\Project\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\..\..\..\..\..\release\APP-1.0.8.apk'.
```

For some reason I am randomly getting this error when trying to run my react native app on android via the react native CLI (react-native run-android). What is weird is this happened randomly, everything was working fine, and I made no changes, this just randomly started happening today. I had it running on my emulator, killed my metro server for a second, went to start everything back up via the command and started getting this error. I tried a few things such as deleting the build folder, running gradlew clean, and pretty much every other thing I could find online for this issue and nothing seems to work.

```
C:\Users\PC\stuff\Project\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\..\..\..\..\..\release\APP-1.0.8.apk
```

This path does not exist after apk\debug so I am pretty sure it has to do with that but I have no idea how to fix it. And the fact this happened randomly without me making any changes after everything working perfect has me even more confused lol. Has anyone ran into this that may know how to solve it? After a few hours of messing with it and trying everything possible that was online already I am stumped.

Comment: When I run into issues like this I usually: remove and reinstall node modules, clean gradle build folder (which you say you did), and sometimes I even go as far as rebooting my computer...

Comment: All things I tried. Its frustrating lol. This is weird as hell.

Comment: What happens if you build the apk manually first (`assembleDevDebug`) and then try to run it? Maybe a temporary fix

Comment: I managed to fix it by completely deleting the project folder all together and then restoring from a past commit and npm installing again etc. No idea what caused it, but it seems to have fixed it. I tried restoring to this same commit 30 mins ago and it was still happening so who knows lol.

Comment: I was even able to just re-add the same project right back into the folder and it fixed it lmao. Seems as long as I delete the project folder clean and re-add everything it fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I had to completely delete the project folder. Then I downloaded the project from my repo and just readded it into the folder and reinstalled all the node modules. That fixed it.